# Is the member sum of a subset of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ known (with $g^n \bmod p$)? Is it always $\mod P = 0$?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Let $P$ be a prime and $g$ a value between $2$ and $P$.
Let $M$ be the set of numbers which can be generated with $g$:
$$M = \{g^n\bmod P, \text{ with } 0 < n <P \}$$
If $g$ is a prime root of $P$ all values $1$ to $P-1$ can be generated.
The sum of those would be:
$$S=\sum M = \sum_{n=1}^{P-1} (g^n \bmod P) = \sum_{n=1}^{P-1} n= (P/2)\cdot (P-1)$$

Is there also a formula for values $g$ not a prime root of $P$?
(So for generators $g$ which are only able to generate a subset of   $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$)
**Question:** What is exact sum of such a subset?

---

**Partly solution**:
During testing around I noticed one factor of this sum $S$ seems to be $P$.
So 
$$ S = \sum M = c \cdot P$$
and with this 
$$ 0 \equiv S \bmod P$$

Is that always the case? EDIT: seems to be the case, see comment from  runway44 (edit end)
Any way to calculate this factor $c$?

---

**Example:** $g=13, P=23$
With $g=13$ only half the numbers out of $\mathbb{Z}/23\mathbb{Z}$ can be generated:
$M = \{13,8,12,18,4,6,9,2,3,16,1\}$
sum $S=\sum M = 92$, which is $4 \cdot P$
Why $4$ times? Any way to compute this factor?

Comment: [Prove sum of primitive roots congruent to μ(p−1)(modp)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25452/338051)

Comment: @ kelalaka ty, learned something new. The linked question is similar but could not figure out yet how to use the Moebius function for my question.

Comment: You seem to have answered the main question by yourself. Have you thought about posting your own answer

Comment: @conchild: me? I still could not manage to formulate an answer. In linked page its the sum of primitive roots and not all values. There is no product of two factors. Its a sum of those. Can't see any way to get the value $4$ for my example.

Comment: The sum $S=\sum g^n$ is invariant under multiplication-by-$g$, i.e. $gS=S$, so if $g\ne 1$ then we can multiply $(g-1)S=0$ by $(g-1)^{-1}$ to get $S=0$. Or you can use the (finite) geometric sum formula for $\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}g^n$ to get $(g^m-1)/(g-1)$, which is $0$ since $g^m=1$, where $m$ is the order of $g$ (i.e. the least whole number $m$ for which $g^m$ is $1$, in which case $1,g,\cdots,g^{m-1}$ is all powers of $g$ listed exactly once).

Comment: (The sum of primitive roots is not relevant here. The proof in the accepted answer over there even uses the fact that the sum of powers of $g$ is $0$ unless $g=1$, which verifies your observation but without explanation.)

Comment: @runway44: ty, for explanation but as far I understood it is  only the reason why the sum modulo $P$ is $0$. I'm interested in the exact sum of a subgroup without any modulo. The prime $P$ is only a factor of that sum. I'm interested in the other factor $c$. If this factor is known the exact sum can be computed. E.g. for the example $g=13$, $P=23$ if factor $c=4$ is known the sum $S = c \cdot P = 4 \cdot 23 = 92$ can be computed.

Comment: Dunno, it's an interesting question. The powers of $g$ mod $p$ are a "nice" set, but their representatives in $\{1,\cdots,p-1\}$ we ought to expect to be "not-nice" since the whole point of that choice of representatives is their minimality among positive integers with respect to the linear order, but the subset being multiplicative mod $p$ has nothing to do with this linear ordering. Intermingling linear (additive) / multiplicative features like this is typical of hard problems, e.g. Goldbach or twin prime conjectures. So I wouldn't be surprised if there weren't a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (I observe $S=c\cdot P$ for some integer $c$.) Is that always the case?

**Yes**. Proof follows.

If $g=P$ then $S=0$. We'll disregard this special case in the following.

The set $M$ has $k$ elements, with $k$ the lowest strictly positive integer with $g^k\equiv1\pmod P$. This $k$ is known as the order of $g$ modulo $P$. This $k$ divides $P-1$. $M$ also is $\{g^n\bmod P, \text{ with } 0 \le n <k \}$, and in this later definition the $g^n\bmod P$ are distinct.

It follows $\displaystyle S=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\left(g^n\bmod P\right)$.

Therefore $\displaystyle S\equiv\left(\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}g^n\right)\pmod P$.

$g\ne 1$. Therefore $\displaystyle S\equiv\frac{g^k-1}{g-1}\pmod P$.

It holds $g^k-1\equiv0\pmod P$. Since $P$ is prime and $g\in[2,P]$, $g-1\ne0\pmod P$.

Therefore $S\equiv0\pmod P$. That is $\exists c\in\Bbb Z, S=c\cdot P$

> Any way to calculate this factor $c$?

If $k$ is even, then $c=k/2$. Argument: if $k$ is even and $x\in M$, it can be shown that $x'=P-x\in M$. We can pair the elements of $M$ into $k/2$ pairs which each sum to $P$.

If $k$ is odd, $c\approx k/2$ still holds. An heuristic argument is that $S$ is the sum of $k$ terms about haphazardly distributed in $[1,P-1]$, thus about $P/2$ on average. That's the best I can tell.

Notes:

- $c$ depend only on $k$ and $P$ (not $g$), per the [fundamental theorem of cyclic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups).
- We can efficiently tell the parity of $k$ from $P$ and $g$: write $P-1$ as $2^\lambda z$ for odd $z$; then $g^z\bmod P=1$ iff $k$ is even (as [commented](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/170646) by poncho).
- $k$ can be efficiently found from $P$, $g$, and the factorization of $P-1$.

Comment: ($k$ can also be a product of those primes found with factorization, I left this over to shorten the question)

Comment: So is it known there is no exact answer for odd $k$? Those kind of $k$ would be the interesting one or to be exact if $k$ is a prime as well.

Comment: @J.Doe: I do not know if there is a fast method to find $c$ from $k$ and $P$ with certainty for odd $k$, and if the factorisation of $P-1$ helps. That might be a question for [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com), perhaps [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).

Comment: You don't need to know the factorization of $P-1$ to determine whether $k$ is even or odd; if we denote $z = (P-1)/2^\lambda$ odd (with $\lambda$ being the integer that makes $z$ an odd integer), then if $g^z = 1$, then $k$ is odd, otherwise, it is even.

Comment: @poncho: I'll put that in the answer. My second blatant steal from you today!